# Unable to check all / select all items in a CheckListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have the following code in XAML for a CheckListBox, I have not used the CheckListBox available in Xceed as it is having issues with the mui wrapper I am using for the project.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_TestCase" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}" Margin="172,10,283,15" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox_TestCase" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I would like to check all the items in the "ListBox_TestCase" by using an button click event. I have a List<> which houses the TestCases and the IsChecked status of each testcase item. By using the below code, I can make IsChecked property of all the elements in the list<> true, but in the front end / UI, I can see that all the elements remain unchecked.

```
 private void Button_SelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   foreach (CheckedListItem item in ListBox_TestCase.ItemsSource)
   {
     item.IsChecked = true;                    
   }
 }
```

Please advice. I can see that there is a List.Selectall available but with that I am able to select only the items in the list and not check all checkboxes.

Please advice.

Comment: You should not use code-behind. Have a look at MVVM and the command pattern. Does your property and class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Nope. I did not include `System.ComponentModel` to the project. I can include the `INotifyPropertyChanged` but which event will help chnage the checkbox state?